# Java how to implement a log class that write to a file

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

i'd like to substitute all my `system.out.println` with a `log.println` in my web-app, in order insert all my log not in Eclipse console, but in an apposite file. I want that because i've deployed my web-app under a tomcat docker container.

I've found after some research this class:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;


public class Log{

    private SettingsManager settings;
    private String logFile;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    static Log theInstance = null;

    /**
     * Returns the only available instance of this class, if it exists...
     * instantiates and returns it otherwise. LOg file name is retrieved 
     * through the SettingsManager
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static Log getInstance() {
        if (Log.theInstance == null) {
            Log.theInstance = new Log();
        }
    return Log.theInstance;
    }   

    private Log() {
        this.settings = SettingsManager.getInstance();
        this.logFile = settings.getString("settings.log.filename");
        try {
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.logFile, true), true);      
            writer.println("*** Kerberos Logfile ***");
            writer.println(" *** Logging started ***");     
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getLogFile() {
        return this.logFile;
    }

    public void println(String line) {
        writer.println("[" + new Date().toString() + "]" + line);   
    }

}
```

Well, how can i modify this singleton class (I've no class named "SettingsManager") and substitute all my `system.out.println` with `log.println`? How can i set my log path?

Or.. can someone show me a simple log class and how to instanciate it?

Comment: It seems that you don't have much knowledge about many java basics in the first place. So instead of thinking how to write something that runs inside tomcat ... you should rather spend a lot of time learning those basics. And then you use your favorite search engine, to well, search for terms like **singleton**. There is a **ton** of documentation around that out there ...

Comment: Sorry, i've expressed myself bad. I know this is a singleton class. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use some logging library like Log4j. Read tutorials/document and implement in your code. Do not copy exactly someone's code and then use.

You can check below tutorial for example:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html